# C printf Segmentation fault (core dumped) while mixing with Assembly code

Tags: c, linux, assembly

I tried some basic example of mixing C code and x86 Assembly code.
It is simple **Find smaller number** example.

Here is Assembly code in b.s file (I have to use intel syntax with no prefix and i386 architecture):

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
.arch i386

.data
    .globl out_format
    out_format:
        .asciz "min(%i, %i) = %i\n"

.text
    .globl min
    .type min, @function
    min:
        enter 0, 0
        mov ebx, [ebp + 8]
        cmp ebx, [ebp + 12]
        jle 1f
        mov eax, [ebp] + 12
        jmp 2f
        1:
            mov eax, ebx
        2:
            leave
        ret 8

.end
```

Here is the C code in a.c file:

```
#include<stdio.h>

extern char out_format;

extern int min(int x, int y);

int main() {
    int x1, x2, r;
    scanf("%i%i", &x1, &x2);
    r = min(x1, x2);
    printf(&out_format, x1, x2, r);

    return 0;
}
```

I compile it with gcc on x64 Arch Linux:

```
gcc -m32 -Wall -Werror -g -o p b.s a.c
```

But when I start the executable file p, and insert 2 numbers and hit enter
I get:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I researched all previous similar questions, and I tried several things but every time I get the same error.
I also tried to debug it with gdb, and I see that Assembly function ***min*** returns the right result, but somehow it always stuck on C ***printf*** function.

I tried to not import string ***out_format*** from Assembly file, and define it directly in C file (I defined it as simple array of chars, and also as char pointer using ***malloc*** and ***free*** functions) but it didn't help.

Otherwise the program doesn't give such error if I intialize variable ***r*** with some integer instead with result of Assembly function ***min***. But it doesn't have any sense to me as I already checked it with gdb and the Assembly function correctly intialize the variable **r** with correct smaller number.

Please, can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to add C variant of the same function to see what C compiler will produce. The problem looks to be in `ret 8`, that's not correct linux 32b calling convention. Check https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/intel386-psABI-1.1.pdf (Paragraphs 2.x mainly, Table 2.3, Table 2.4) -> `esp` should be preserved, so you should use `ret` instead. Where did you get the `ret 8`? (that looks like win32 knowledge)

Comment: In addition to the `ret 8` problem, you are also not preserving `ebx` which is a callee-saved register.

Comment: @Ped7g When I add the C variant of the Assembly min function and preserve import of the out_format it works ok. Also if I remove just remove C printf command, but leave the imports and calling the Assembly min function, it also works but I don't see result, because the code doesn't print anything. The ret 8 is used because the Assembly min function should use stdcall convenction insetad of the default cedcl. According to the stdcall even if I change the import of the function min in C code to look like this: extern int __attribute__((stdcall)) min(int x, int y); I always get the same error :(

Comment: I meant: try to add C variant (also make it `stdcall`), and check the disassembly / debugger, how it differs from yours. In OP there was no mention of stdcall, so it will not work by default. If you add `stdcall` specifier, you can still check disassembly if the `main` takes that into account and calls it correctly, expecting the `esp` to be modified. ... also if you use cdecl, fix `ret` and fix `ebx`, does it work then?

Comment: After preserving ebx in Assembly code right below the enter command it works. That was the catch, I forgot to do that at all. Thaks for your help and also to Jester.

Answer (score 0):

if min() works good, check out_format.

following code works.

```
printf("%d %d %d\n", x1, x2, r);
```

full code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int min(int x, int y)
{
    if (x<y) return x;
    return y;
}

int main() {
    int x1, x2, r;
    scanf("%i%i", &x1, &x2);
    r = min(x1, x2);
    printf("%d %d %d\n", x1, x2, r);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry but what exactly you did and it worked? I tried to put same thing in my code, explicitly in C code from the above, also I tried to change the out_format in Assembly code according to your snippet but I always get the same error.

Comment: you need implementation of min(). it should be on different source code or library. if not, implement min() function.

Comment: int min (int x, int y) { if (x<y) return x; return y}

Comment: I see you want to use assembly and C. out_format is char in C code, in assembly code it's string - array of character. use out_format[] in C code

Comment: The problem is the `ret 8` in the asm which doesn't match the standard Linux calling convention (where the caller pops the args).  There was nothing wrong with the OP's format string or using the asm-defined data.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I just want to leave the code that works.

File b.s:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
.arch i386

.data
    .globl out_format
    out_format:
        .asciz "min(%i, %i) = %i\n"

.text
    .globl min
    .type min, @function
    min:
        enter 0, 0
        push ebx
        mov ebx, [ebp + 8]
        cmp ebx, [ebp + 12]
        jle 1f
        mov eax, [ebp] + 12
        jmp 2f
        1:
            mov eax, ebx
        2:
            pop ebx
            leave
        ret 8

.end
```

File a.c:

```
#include<stdio.h>

extern char out_format;

extern int __attribute__((stdcall)) min(int x, int y);

int main() {
    int x1, x2, r;
    scanf("%i%i", &x1, &x2);
    r = min(x1, x2);
    printf(&out_format, x1, x2, r);

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks everyone for their help.

Comment: Or better, use `ret` instead of `ret 8` to use the normal calling convention.  This would be a better answer if you described what you changed.  (Just the `__attribte__((stdcall))`?)

Comment: Also, you can use `extern char out_format[]` to use a more accurate declaration.

Answer (score 0):

The asm uses `ret 8` to pop the args from the stack as it returns.

The standard 32-bit x86 Linux calling convention ([i386 System V ABI](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI)) is caller-pops.  **Functions just use `ret` to return** and the caller can clean up the stack if / when it wants.  (e.g. use `mov` stores to write new args before another `call` instead of adjusting `esp` and using `push` again.)

As the OP's self answer points you, you could instead declare `min` as

```
extern int __attribute__((stdcall)) min(int x, int y);
```

so the compiler-generated code will agree with the asm on the calling convention.  This calling convention is sometimes used on Windows.

Single-stepping with a debugger would have revealed this (if you knew what to look for).  Always use a debugger to figure out where your code segfaults, then look at registers and work backwards to find out why.